# Svg D3.js How to selectAll using condition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, conditional-statements, subset

Assume that there are lots of group (`<g/>`) elements in the page body. Some of these group elements have id, some of them not, however there is an interest only in those group elements which has an `id` which begins with string `foo`.

How can you operate only on subset of selected elements?

There is a need of something like this:

```
d3.selectAll("g").where(id like 'foo%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[] selects attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) and ^= means begins with so you end up with this...

```
d3.selectAll("g[id^=foo]")
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using selectors to do the filtering, you can also use D3's [`.filter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) function:

```
d3.selectAll("g").filter(function(d) { return this.id.match(/foo/).length > 0; });
```

Comment: Sorry that should have been `this`.